# Is there any website like OEIS for special polynomials

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, online-resources, oeis

I would like to know if there is any kind of website (like OEIS) in which we can search for special known polynomials. For example, we put the coefficients of Legendre's and then the website gives us the result: "This is the Legendre Polynomial $P_n$..."

Thanks

Comment: If there isn't, are you planning to create one?

Comment: To be honest, I was not thinking on this when I asked. But, after your question, if I could I would.

Comment: Technically this is very difficult, how do you search for mathematical formulas? Also, there are a huge number of trivial algebraic transformations you can do on the coefficients (e.g. $\sqrt{\frac1{2\pi}}$ and $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2\pi}$...). How do you recognize all of those?

Comment: If the coefficients are integral or rational, you can as well search on OEIS.

Comment: Yeah, pretty hard indeed.. Well, thanks. I'll use OEIS.